# How to check if date has expired

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, mktime

I'm trying to check if post has expired, here is what i've tried till now

```
$p = "08"; //suppose month is Aug
$m="2016"; //year is 2016
$input_time = mktime(0,0,0,$p+1,0,$m); 

if ($input_time < time()){
   print '<p class = "error">Post has expired</p>';

}
else{
echo 'Post is still fresh';
}
```

In above example i can only check month & year, How can i also check day,month & year ?

Comment: Do you mean expired means if it is not from the month and year given in inputs? Can you explain what do you mean by expired with respect to current date?

Comment: if the given expire date is 04/08/2016 & today date is 05/08/2016, then it means post has expire

Comment: So you need to find if post date is today's date or not if it's lesser then it's expired, isn't it? @Aniket Singh

Comment: Please search before asking. Basically every date comparison question has been asked and answered by now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$curdate = strtotime('05-08-2016');
$mydate = strtotime('04-08-2016');

if($curdate > $mydate)
{
    echo 'Post is Expired';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-09', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
var_dump($date->getTimestamp()<time()); //true

$date = new DateTime('2016-09', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
var_dump($date->getTimestamp()<time()); //false

$date = new DateTime('2016-08-06', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
var_dump($date->getTimestamp()<time()); //false

$date = new DateTime('2016-08-04', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
var_dump($date->getTimestamp()<time()); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime("input time");` and use it for checking

Answer (score 0):

If I have got your problem, the solution is so easy. Just pass day instead of zero in the fifth parameter:

```
$d='12';
$input_time = mktime(0,0,0,$p+1,$d,$m);
```

Comment: It's showing post is fresh again & again